# curl: Unexpected token in JSON

Tags: json, bash, curl

When I try to submit this, the sever sends me back the message

`"Unexpected token t in JSON at position 1".`

And it'll do that with whatever the first non { non " character is. If I input {"": ""} it'll say

```
"Unexpected token : in JSON at position 1".
```

This is my code .

```
  curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {"test": "test"} url
```

I've tried other variants of putting quotes around it and escaping quotes to no avail, but if you think that's the issue feel free to suggest a format.

Comment: As for cURL and Bash accepting it on command line, this `-d '{"test": "test"}'` worked for me. Try removing the space after the colon to satisfy JSON validation on server side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to protect the double quotes as well as the spaces.  You can do so with single quotes, thus:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"test": "test"}' url
```

Without the single quotes, shell treats the double quotes as a part of the syntax and strips them, and hence `curl` would only see

```
{test:
```

as the argument for `-d` option, and

```
test}
```

is sent as a separate argument.  With the double quotes in place, `curl` will see this as the argument to `-d`:

```
{"test": "test"}
```

You can also achieve this with backslashes, which is a little cumbersome:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {\"test\":\ \"test\"} url
```

---

See these related posts / documentation:

- [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)
- [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)
- [Quoting in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. That was like the one thing I didn't try. Why does that work but not

    {\"test\": \"test\"}

Comment: With `\`, you are able to protect the double quotes.  However, you are not protecting the space.  {\"test\":\ \"test\"} should work.

Comment: In more detail, if you don't quote the space, the argument to `-d` is `{"test":` and the argument after the space is separate.

Comment: Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable